# Recursively search groups under specific ou for a user in LDAP

Tags: performance, recursion, ldap

We currently have an LDAP deployment with millions of users and hundreds of thousands of groups (if not millions), so doing a full recursive lookup for a user takes >3m per query.

I'm needing to find all groups for a user, but only for groups under a specific OU, as others are not relevant and are a waste of search time.

Is there a search for LDAP that can reduce the amount of searching required for the group lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Does your directory stamp the membership on the Users?  eDirectory does (groupMembership). Active Directory does a synthetic attribute that does the lookup when you query the attribute memberOf.

Consider stamping that on the users, then as you look at a user, the data you want is stored on the User. Not in the thousands of groups out there, where youo have to go look to see which the user is a member.